# PHP SoapClient code completion

Tags: php, soap

Let's imagine a standard piece of code using SoapClient in PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient(/* arguments here */);
$result1 = $client->invokeSomeApiMethod($arg1, $arg2);
$result2 = $client->invokeSomeOtherApiMethod($arg3);
```

I'm wondering, is there a way to specify an API of a particular service to an IDE (I'm using PhpStorm) in order to get code completion, basic arguments validation and so on, so that IDE would know that invokeSomeApiMethod really exists for this particular SoapClient instance and it accepts some list of arguments.

The only way I see for the moment is to declare a class whose interface would correspond the API of the web service and create an annotation for SoapClient instance:

```
class SomeApi extends SoapClient
{
    public function invokeSomeApiMethod($arg1, $arg2)
    {
    }

    public function invokeSomeOtherApiMethod($arg3, $arg4 = null)
    {
    }
}

/** @var SomeApi $client */
$client = new SoapClient(/* arguments here */);
```

But for me it looks quite weird. Maybe someone of you uses any other approach?

Comment: Its not weird .. not all IDE would load WSDL at runtime so that you can have access to SOAP method calls

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about a more general thing, a way to specify in IDE the API which the object implements dynamically. There are a lot of examples like that, for example view helpers in Zend Framework:

    $view = new ZendView();
    $view->url(/* arguments */);

The url method doesn't physically exists for ZendView instance, but it's implemented via __call() magic method. And so on.